# Error: stack/package not found

Tags: ros, stack, ros-fuerte, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I have just added a new package to my workspace, but ROS can not see the package and give the error :

I know I have to source it, but I just do not know how... `Error: stack/package not found#`

Please do not refer me ROS tutorial page, especially the first or third tutorial :) I do not ask here before trying ros tutorials page or internet in the end :)

I need a step by step answer, not something go that tutorial or look that page.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/76114/error:-stack/package-not-found/) by [mary](https://answers.ros.org/users/5710/mary/) on ROS Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-09-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-03**:
What did you do to "added a new package to my workspace"? What did you do to get the error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I found the solution. `rosws set <name of package>`

---

Originally posted by [mary](https://answers.ros.org/users/5710/mary/) with karma: 43 on 2013-09-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1